# Why are these meshes considered nonmanifold?

Tags: manifolds

[image: nonmanifold]
Why are these vertices and edges considered nonmanifold?
What is the correct name for these surfaces(other than nonmanifold)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not manifolds because they do not fulfiull the definition. Specifically, they do not "look like $\mathbb R^n$" in the marked parts. They qualify as [CW complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex), however.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! I have further questions if you don't mind. Is neighbourhood of non-manifold vertice not open? And neighbourhood of non-manifold edge is not homeomorphic to disk? Can these surfaces be called algebraic varieties(which have singular points as opposed to manifolds)?

Comment: They are also simplicial complexes. @pusheax: They are not algebraic varieties: Such a variety has the property that link of every point has even Euler characteristic. In particular, this link cannot be contractible.